# Parsing XML Dom to a Python List using mindom

Tags: python, xml

I have a XML file that I fetch from a website. I have placed the XML in a DOM and I am able to get most of the needed information from it except where I have the following:

```
<response>
  <result name="response" numFound="2567888" start="0">
    <doc>
      <int name="ImageCount">3</int>
      <arr name="Images">
        <str>binder/jnws/jnws40/images/p1120.jpg</str>
        <str>binder/jnws/jnws40/images/g0753.jpg</str>
        <str>binder/jnws/jnws40/images/p0754.jpg</str>
      </arr>
    </doc>
  </result>
</response>
```

My Code is:

```
for node in solardom.getElementsByTagName('doc'):
  # Get the Image Count & Video Counts for this doc element ..."
  imageCount = int(getMyElementValue(node, "int", "ImageCount"))
  videoCount = int(getMyElementValue(node, "int", "VideoCount"))
  if imageCount > 0:
    print "Image Count is: " + str(imageCount)
    imageList = getMyList(node, "arr", "Images", imageCount)

def getMyList(n, ntype, s, num):
  list = []
  i = 0
  for node in n.getElementsByTagName(ntype):
    if node.getAttribute("name") == s:
      print "Found Image Path!!!"
```

I see that I am at the correct level in the XML but I can't figure out how to stuff the string value for the image paths into a Python list.

Thanks for any assistance or pointers you can give me.
Jake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `return [child.nodeValue for child in node.childNodes]`.

Comment: Thanks, I think it is getting closer but it is not returning anything in the list.

I changed my code to:

    def getMyList(n, ntype, s, num):
 for node in n.getElementsByTagName(ntype):
  if node.getAttribute("name") == s:
   print "Found Image Path!!!"
   return [child.nodeValue for child in node.childNodes]

and I get back:

    Image Count is: 3
    Found Image Path!!!
    [None, None, None]

Comment: right, try '[child.firstChild.nodeValue for child in node.childNodes if child.firstChild != None]'.

Answer (score 0):

Try [xmltodict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xmltodict) module.

```
>>> import xmltodict
>>> obj = xmltodict.parse(xml)
>>> print(obj['response']['result']['doc']['arr']['str'])
>>> ['binder/jnws/jnws40/images/p1120.jpg', 'binder/jnws/jnws40/images/g0753.jpg', 'binder/jnws/jnws40/images/p0754.jpg']
```

Comment: Yes I would love to use something other than minidom but the company I work for won't let me install these mods.  When I try xmltodict I get the "ImportError: No module named xmltodict".

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this

```
xml = '''
  <response>
  <result name="response" numFound="2567888" start="0">
    <doc>
      <int name="ImageCount">3</int>
      <arr name="Images">
        <str>binder/jnws/jnws40/images/p1120.jpg</str>
        <str>binder/jnws/jnws40/images/g0753.jpg</str>
        <str>binder/jnws/jnws40/images/p0754.jpg</str>
      </arr>
    </doc>
  </result>
 </response>
'''

>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> root = ET.fromstring(xml)    
>>> imgs = [img.text for img in root.findall(".//*[@name='Images']/str")]
>>> ['binder/jnws/jnws40/images/p1120.jpg', 'binder/jnws/jnws40/images/g0753.jpg', 'binder/jnws/jnws40/images/p0754.jpg']
```

You can read more [here](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree)